# Zooming a UIScrollView in MonoTouch

Tags: c#, iphone, ios, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to implement zooming functionality using a UIScrollView in MonoTouch but I just can't seem to make it work.

I've looked at a few tutorials which talk about setting a Delegate but most of it is in Obj-C which I can't translate over to C#.

Basically, I have a UIScrollView in Interface Builder that has an UIImageView as a Subview.

I've set the ContentSize of the UIScrollView to be the full size of the image and have also set a min/max zoom scale. Here's my code:

```
UIImage imgMap = new UIImage("img/map.png");
ivMap.Image = imgMap;
svMap.MinimumZoomScale = 1.0f;
svMap.MaximumZoomScale = 3.0f;
svMap.ContentSize = new System.Drawing.SizeF(ivMap.Frame.Width, ivMap.Frame.Height);
```

Any ideas on what I'm missing?

**EDIT**

I've created a new .xib file with the code provided by @Geoff but still no luck, the image just scrolls but still doesn't zoom.

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad ();

    UIScrollView sv = new UIScrollView (thisView.Frame);
    UIImageView iv = new UIImageView(UIImage.FromFile ("img/map.png"));

    sv.AddSubview (iv);
    sv.ContentSize = iv.Frame.Size;
    sv.MinimumZoomScale = 1.0f;
    sv.MaximumZoomScale = 3.0f;

    vwMineral.AddSubview(sv);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
var sv = new UIScrollView (window.Frame);
var iv = new UIImageView (UIImage.FromFile ("pat.jpg"));

sv.AddSubview (iv);
sv.ContentSize = iv.Frame.Size;
sv.MinimumZoomScale = 1.0f;
sv.MaximumZoomScale = 3.0f;
sv.MultipleTouchEnabled = true;
sv.ViewForZoomingInScrollView = delegate(UIScrollView scrollView) {
    return iv;
};      

window.AddSubview (sv);
window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Geoff, I've just created a new .xib file with just the code you've provided above and once again I can just scroll the image but not zoom-in/out. I've also tried enabling the "Multiple Touch" option in IB but same thing - I can only scroll. P.S. the image size is quite large, 1490x1320 to be exact. Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: oops, sorry, I've updated my answer with the complete solution.

Comment: That's it, I was just missing the `ViewForZoomingInScrollView` part. Thanks