# Implementing Delegate Callback method in MonoTouch

Tags: c#, delegates, xamarin.ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Zooming a UIScrollView in MonoTouch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011243/zooming-a-uiscrollview-in-monotouch)

I need to implement this objective-c delegate callback in my application:

```
-(UIView *) viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)inScroll {
  return imageView;
}
```

However I'm using MonoTouch to develop my application, how do I go about implementing delegates in MonoTouch?  (I'm aware I'm probably not using the correct terminology in regards to 'implementing delegates in MonoTouch', please advise).

Here is the code which I need to delegate callback for (I need the imageview within the scrollview to be zoomable):

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();

        Loader loader = new Loader("/Users/jacknutkins/Documents/ARCSDev");
        loader.LoadChart("2");
        CGBitmapContext context = loader.GetHiResImage(loader.PaletteFile.RGBPaletteDay);
        UIImage image = UIImage.FromImage(context.ToImage());
        this.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;
        RectangleF rect = new RectangleF(0.0f, 0.0f, image.Size.Width, image.Size.Height);
        //RectangleF rect = new RectangleF(scrollView.Frame.Location, scrollView.Frame.Size);
        UIImageView imageView = new UIImageView(rect);
        imageView.Image = image;
        scrollView.ContentSize = image.Size;
        scrollView.AddSubview(imageView);
        scrollView.ClipsToBounds = true;
        scrollView.SetZoomScale(0.5f, true);
        Console.WriteLine("View Did Load Done.");
        // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
```

Tysin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just add an event handler to the ViewForZoomingInScrollView event:

```
scrollView.ViewForZoomingInScrollView += (UIScrollView sv) => 
{
    return null;
};
```